# ThreeJS add images to each face on object loaded from json

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've a 3D bag model loaded from JSON file, now i want to add different image's to each face of bag. My process is

1. Load JSON file with JSONLoader
2. Create new materials MeshBasicMaterial
3. Draw object

This is my code

```
var image;        
var materials = [];
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load("bag.json", function (model) {
for (var i=0; i<6; i++) {
    image = (i+1)+".jpg";
    materials.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(image), overdraw: true}));
}

    var materialSix = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);

    object = new THREE.Mesh(model, materialSix);
    object.translateY(1);
    object.scale = new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1);

      scene.add(object);
});
```

But it only display one  image on all faces. I want to add image to front, back, left, right side. How to fix this problem ?

Comment: This kind of thing is much easier to do inside of a modeling tool, like Blender, and then import the whole thing (including textures) into three.js. Is there any reason that wouldn't be an option?

Comment: Did you test first with a BoxGeometry...? Examples I can see online are similar to yours but simpler geometry, if that works could be an issue with how the JSONLoader is creating the geometry ...

Comment: @DonMcCurdy I'm using Maya to create 3D model on website, and need to change materials, size..etc dynamic. That's why i need to apply image to each face.

Comment: @PhilippeLeefsma i tried with BoxGeometry but it's invalid when loading object from json file

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that you don't load object from JSON but use simple BoxGeometry instead and see if your MeshFaceMaterial works this way. If it does work then the issue is how the JSONLoader is creating the geometry, which might be different than predefined geometries, at least it *might* give you a clue ...

Comment: I meant to say you can use Maya to put the images onto the shape. See tutorials for texturing in Maya. Doing this in threejs with arbitrary models will be much harder.